# The method map(Task, Class<TaskDto>) is undefined for the type ModelMapper TaskController.java

Tags: java, spring

I'm currently working on a project in Springboot, and while I'm busy, I am getting this error:

```
The method map(Task, Class<TaskDto>) is undefined for the type ModelMapper TaskController.java
```

I searched it on the internet, but i can't find the solution that fits the problem.

I'm using this function

TaskController

```
@Autowired
private ModelMapper modelMapper;

private TaskDto toDto(Task task) {
    TaskDto taskDto = modelMapper.map(task, TaskDto.class);
    return taskDto;
}
```

ModelMapper

```
public class ModelMapper {
    
    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }
    
}
```

Dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
    <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: the error message seems clear enough ... you don't have a map method.

Answer (score 1):

You should use ModelMapperConfig to create bean of ModelMapper. Name of class should not be ModelMapper because you are creating a bean of that class using dependency.

```
@Configuration
public class ModelMapperConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }
    
}
```

Hope this will work for you!

You can refer this site for the same.
https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application

Comment: I changed the name of the class as you said, but still the same error

Comment: You can see the code in here: https://codeshare.io/ad37Pz

Comment: Have you imported your configuration into your main config class? If not please do or else create bean into the main config class

Comment: Do you mean the Main.java?

Comment: Yes, Your main class in which contains @SpringBootApplication annotation and main method

Comment: I move the method  public ModelMapper modelMapper() {...} to the main class, and now its works. Thanks a lot